# Doesn't work diff command (arguments troubles)

Tags: linux, bash, rpm

Trying to do diff by typing next:

```
$ diff -c $(rpm -qpR prev/p.src.rpm 2>/dev/null) $(rpm -qpR curr/p.src.rpm 2>/dev/null)

diff: extra operand `<='
diff: Try `diff --help' for more information.
```

How can I change my arguments for normal script working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you try executing the script this way:

```
$ diff -c <(rpm -qpR prev/p.src.rpm 2>/dev/null) <(rpm -qpR curr/p.src.rpm 2>/dev/null)
```

This should substitute the command between "<()" as a process. This will create a named pipe and they will be given to diff as a file to compare. Allowing you to execute the above directly in a script.

Comment: if u still can read: on one system this work well, on another it gave me:
    diff: /dev/fd/63: No such file or directory
    diff: /dev/fd/62: No such file or directory

Answer (score 1):

Dump the `ls` outputs into files and diff those; don't [shave the yak](http://www.catb.org/~esr/jargon/html/Y/yak-shaving.html).

Comment: ths a lot! did't hear before so apt turn of phrase! but sometimes the way to solve a trouble much interesting than kind of trouble )